# Android create file on internal storage, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android

```
        String filename = job_no + ".csv";
        File newfile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), filename);
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newfile), 64);
            byte[] bb = resultfile.getBytes();
            out.write(bb);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("", e.toString());
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?, it doesnt show any error messages and doesn't create any files...

i'm checking it with this

```
  try { 
     String workbook_xml = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
     Log.d(workbook_xml, "");  
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
       Log.d("", "sdfsdfsdfsdf"); 
  }
```

it comes back as `sdfsdfsdfsdf error (FileNotFOund)`

Comment: how do you know that it's not creating the file? How are you checking it?

Comment: i'm checking it with this
'try {
                   String workbook_xml = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                   Log.d(workbook_xml, "");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("", "sdfsdfsdfsdf");
            }'

Comment: it comes back as sdfsdfsdfsdf error (FileNotFOund)

Comment: but then the check is wrong. It should be `new Scanner(new File(getFilesDir(), filename))`

Comment: how do i accept your answer. You are COMPLETELY RIGHT, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking it in the wrong way

```
new Scanner(new File(filename))
```

should  be

```
new Scanner(new File(getFilesDir(), filename))
```